# android studio 3.0 version showing following error while adding recyclerview dependency in bulild.gradle

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.0

Error image
[image]

I recently updated my android studio to 3.0 and while i was adding dependency for recycler view in build.gradle(module.app) whereas card view is working fine.It's showing the shown error.Below is my dependency code.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.m.listviewslow"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add  **maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }** in your project level build.gradle .

```
    allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
}
```

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html

Answer (score 0):

Edit your build.gradle file like this

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```